# How can I get properties stored in ConfigAdmin?

Tags: java, osgi

I've created the ConfigAdmin loaded some properties. After that I've saved them. My question is: how can I get the properties that I have stored?
I've created the ConfigAdmin in the Activator.java:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private String configFile = "API.properties";
    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        InputStream stream = (bundleContext.getBundle().getResource(configFile)).openStream();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(stream);
        createConfigAdmin(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {

    }
    private boolean createConfigAdmin(Properties properties, BundleContext context) {
        try {
            Dictionary<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            ServiceReference reference = context.getServiceReference(ConfigurationAdmin.class.getName());
            ConfigurationAdmin admin = (ConfigurationAdmin) context.getService(reference);
            Configuration configuration = admin.createFactoryConfiguration(pid.configAdminPID, null);
            for(final String name: properties.stringPropertyNames())
                props.put(name, properties.getProperty(name));
            configuration.update(props);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was your intention really to create a factory config? You only need it if you want to create several configs for the same factory pid. 
If you simply want to create a simple configuration then just use admin.getConfiguration(oid) you can update the configuration in the same way you do now.

If you want to read the configuration afterwards you simply get it again. If you want to configure a bundle with this configuration you typically will create a ManagedService and publish it. See http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/09/23/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+2+-+Using+the+Configuration+Admin+Service

Comment: Basically I need ConfigAdmin for sharing properties to other classes (in the same bundle)  load from a file.properties How can I achieve this goal using ConfigAdmin? We are using equinox (but I think is the same for Karaf)

Comment: Just configure config admin like it is done in karaf. As you see in the tutorial karaf auto loads configs from the etc dir. So your application just needs to react on the config instead of reading the files. Install the felix config admin and fileinstall bundles and configure them like karaf does: https://gist.github.com/cschneider/f66fd5a3eeaa84e56bd2