# How to remove CXF from rest service URL dynamically using admin config services

Tags: osgi, cxf, karaf, blueprint-osgi

I am new to OSGI. I have developed a student rest service using cxf and blueprint .Deployed it in karaf. By default karaf has cxf in its URL. I have found that i can configure the property(org.apache.cxf.servlet.context=/student) in etc folder or I can run config:edit/setprop/update/ commands in karaf. So that i can replace cxf in the url with some custom value. But now I want to remove the CXF from my url without doing any above mentioned changes in karaf. Is there any other way I can do the same? I found that using admin config service and configuration I can update the above property but it is not working.

I referred following link:
[How can I get properties stored in ConfigAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582580/how-can-i-get-properties-stored-in-configadmin) -It didn't work for me.

As am using blueprint do I need to add anything extra? and what is exactly factorypid and location which I have to pass to createFactoryConfiguration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you try to do. You seem to have found already how to change the cxf servlet context to something else.

Comment: I remember that you can explicitly set the address on CXF bean. This allows to specify port and url

Comment: Am able to remove CXF from URL using  (admin.getConfiguration("org.apache.cxf.osgi")).update(props) and update it with the new value ie /student(here admin is ConfigurationAdmin reference variable and props is a dictionary with key "org.apache.cxf.servlet.context", value "/student"). Same is working fine in karaf. But when I try the same in equinox it is not working. Am I missing something?While debugging i saw the config returned from Equinox had following org.eclipse.equinox.internal.cm.ConfigurationImpl@13e23499. But karaf had details about org.apache.cxf.osgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found solution for my issue. Add following code to activator's start method.

```
  Dictionary<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
  props.put( "org.apache.cxf.servlet.context", "/student" );
  // Use OSGI admin configuration to update CXF url
  ServiceReference reference = context.getServiceReference( ConfigurationAdmin.class.getName() );
  ConfigurationAdmin admin = (ConfigurationAdmin) context.getService( reference );
  try
  {
     Configuration config = admin.getConfiguration( "org.apache.cxf.osgi", null );
     config.update( props );
  }
  catch ( Exception exception )
  {
              throw exception;
  }
```

No need to do any changes in blueprint.xml. It works in both karaf and equinox. Initially i was trying in equinox without passing location argument to getConfiguration() hence it was not working.